# How do I append children into a div in one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want an element to first be replaced with a div then that div will have some children by append():

```
$(el).html('<div></div>').append('<span></span>').append('<span></span>')
```

doesn't give me what I want since the div and the spans are siblings.

I also tried:

```
$(el).replaceWith('<div></div>').append('<span></span>').append('<span></span>')
```

without success. This line doesn't work with AngularJS (directives).

Is there a simple way to make the spans children of the div?

UPDATE:

This is what I ended up using:

```
$(element)
  .html($('<div class="property-filter"></div>')
  .append(labelElm)
  .append(amountElm)
  .append(sliderElm));
```

since it was simple to understand (to me).

Thanks for all the solutions!

Comment: I'm curious as to why this must be done in one line? Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I know. But if it's possible that would be better. Less code. More succinct code.

Comment: Just because you're writing LESS code, doesn't mean you are doing a good thing. Think about the readability of your code as you go from left to right. What happens when you come back months later and you need to debug? Your readability decreases with each function you daisy-chain onto the last. If you want less code in production, why not use a tool to minify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does not work because `$(el).html('<div></div>')` returns `$(el)`. It is for chain of methods.

```
$(el).html($('<div></div>').append('<span></span>').append('<span></span>'));​
```

Or

```
$('<div></div>').append('<span></span>').append('<span></span>').appendTo(el);
```

Comment: @wingy, You said "I want an element to first be replaced with a div". This just appends the div to what's already there.

Comment: His original solution was correct. I have told him to change it back. If he doesn't I'll mark this one as the correct answer.

Comment: Strange it worked for me. Either way, he didn't change it so here you go. Good job fighting the point back! :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply do this?

```
$(el).html('<div><span></span><span></span></div>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var div= $('<div></div>')
var mm= $('<span>b</span>')
var combnd= div.append(mm)
var fresult=combnd.append(mm)
fresult.appendTo(el)​
```

Comment: Added a missed `'` on the first line

Comment: Didn't work. They are still siblings. And what is the difference other than assigning the spans to a variable as jQuery elements?

Comment: Actually it worked now. The original one. Haven't use the newer one.

Comment: @speransky danil: My mistake i just rename it, now it will work

Comment: Your first one was better! I added the original one as the solution. Perhaps changing it back?

Answer (score 1):

`$(el).html($('<div />').append('<span></span>').append('<span></span>'))`

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
var div = $('<div></div>').append('<span></span>').append('<span></span>');

$(el).parent().html(div);​
```

Answer (score 1):

This replaces the contents of the `$(el)` like you asked:

```
$(el).html('<span />').append('<span />').wrapInner('<div />');​
```